# Yet another jdbc:mysql no suitable driver, Spring+Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, jdbc

I'm trying to get a MySQL database connection running in a Spring/Hibernate project in NetBeans. However, I always get a

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test"
```

exception when deploying. None of the solutions I've read so far solve my problem.

*applicationContext.xml:*

```
<bean id="myDataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      p:url="${database.url}"
      p:username="${database.username}"
      p:password="${database.password}" />
```

where database.* is stored in a properties file. The jdbc connector .jar file is listed in libraries (ie. the classpath is set). When I expand it, com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is listed.

I have tried the natively installed connector and downloaded the newest version I could find (5.1.15). I can connect a jdbc connector that I have configured earlier using the same driver by clicking "connect" within the serviced tab in NetBeans. When using this sample code from outside the IDE, it also works:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;
public class DBDemo
{
 private static final String dbClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 private static final String CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test";
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
 {
   System.out.println(dbClassName);
   Class.forName(dbClassName);
   Properties p = new Properties();
   p.put("user","root");
   p.put("password","root");
   Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION,p);
   System.out.println("It works !");
   c.close();
 }
}
```

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the driver was missing, you'd rather have seen a `ClassNotFoundException`.

This particular one means that no one of the loaded drivers accepts the given URL. I'd say, those quotes look suspicious, they normally don't appear in this exception. Where does `${database.url}` come from? Does it contain quotes? Get rid of them.

Comment: quotes are from the properties file, but it still produces the same error if i remove the quotes

Comment: You did rebuild/redeploy/restart?

Comment: Is the exception message now quoteless? If not, then it was probably not done properly.

Comment: Ok, I just (1) removed the quotes, (2) cleaned the build, (3) restarted NetBeans, and (4) redeployed. It works :)) Must have been some combination of the above. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you deployed your application on web-container ? If yes, then are you sure that mysql db driver is packaged within WEB-INF/lib directory (in deployment).

The expanded jar that you see under library in Netbeans might not mean it would be able to your web-app on deployment site.

Comment: the deployment site is just the dist directory for now, and the connector library is there